# How to update SQL Server column after from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table called TableA that stored list of event like this

```
Event_Id     Event_Name
1            Found in AD
2            Found in AAD
```

I have another table call Table B and it look something like this

```
Event_Id    UserName      Extra
NULL        David         Found In AAD
1           James         Found in AD
Null        Ronal         Null
```

I'm just trying to update only a missing/Null value in TableB **Event_ID** column based on comparing Table1 **Event_Name** and TableB **Extra** columns.

I'm doing manually process like this for now so I would be really appreciated If I can get any help on how to join directly between the two table and update it.

```
Update Table B
  Set Event_Id = case
         when Extra = 'Found in AAD' then 2
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple sub-query in your `UPDATE` to do that.

```
UPDATE TableB SET
    Event_Id = (SELECT Event_Id from TableA a where a.Event_Name = TableB.Extra)
WHERE Event_Id is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will look for any matches on the `Event_Name` and `Extra_Name` and update the `Extra` table's `Event_Id` based on the match.

**SQL:**

```
UPDATE 
  Extra_Data 
SET 
  Extra_Data.Event_Id = a.Event_Id 
FROM 
  Event_Data a 
  INNER JOIN Extra_Data b ON a.Event_Name = b.Extra_Name 
WHERE 
  b.Event_Id IS NULL;
```

**Results:**

```
| Event_Id | UserName |   Extra_Name |
|----------|----------|--------------|
|        2 |    David | Found In AAD |
|        1 |    James |  Found in AD |
|   (null) |    Ronal |       (null) |
```

**SQL Fiddle:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3a2ea/7

Answer (score -1):

```
update table_b 
set table_b.Event_Id = table_a.Event_Id 
from table_b
JOIN table_a  
ON table_b.extra  = table_a.Event_Name
```